# RejectedExecutionHandler - CallerRunsPolicy vs AbortPolicy

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

While setting up thread pool configuration, how do you choose the correct `RejectedExecutionHandler`?

I have a legacy application which publishes events (those events could be consumed locally or could be consumed by the remote process). At the moment, the policy is to abort which causes lots of exceptions and missed events. We pass synchronous queue to thread pool executor.

I was thinking of changing the `RejectedExecutionHandler` to caller runs policy. This could mean that caller spending time running that task when the thread bound and queue capacity is reached. I don't see any problem with that.

What has been your experience so far? Also, Is using unbounded queue means no utility for `RejectedExecutionHandler`?

Answer (score 9):

I think you are already familiar with different `RejectedExecutionHandlers` of  [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

> In  [ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy.html), the thread that invokes execute itself runs the task. This provides a simple feedback control mechanism that will slow down the rate that new tasks are submitted.

It will impact overall performance of your application. If your application can afford this delay (*Not Real time and Batch Processing*, *Non-Interactive and Offline*), you can use this policy. If you can't afford delay and fine with discarding that task, you can go for [ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy.html)

> Is using unbounded queue means no utility for RejectedExecutionHandler?

Yes. Unbounded queue means no utility for `RejectedExecutionHandler`. When you are using unbounded queue, make sure that your application throughput is under control with respect to *Memory* and *CPU* utilization. If you are submitting short duration tasks with less memory footprint of data in that task, you can use unbounded queue.

Comment: Thanks for answering, however,  `If you can't afford delay and fine with discarding that task` OR `Not Real time and Batch Processing, Non-Interactive and Offline` are not related and most of the time you want neither. I was looking for use cases where you choose discard policy and what you expect the task submitter to do if the task is rejected.

Comment: If  Rejected task must be processed, then CallerRunsPolicy policy is the only solution at the cost of throughput of the system. Other solution persist these events and process them later in a different ThreadPoolExecutor